# How to send/receive data to USB device connection using Android Hardware USB API?

Tags: android, usb

I have here a Bluefruit LE Feather 32u4 board connected to my Android device that I'm trying to send and receive data to. It's currently programed to echo back what is sent, so I'm trying to figure out the Android API to write and read from it.

Here's some verbose info on the hardware I'm trying to communicate with:
https://pastebin.com/ktyBhzE8

In the test app, there's a button that runs the following code.

```
   private void DoTheThing() {
      String textMessage = "";

      m_usbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);

      HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = m_usbManager.getDeviceList();
      Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();
      while (deviceIterator.hasNext()) {
         m_usbDevice = deviceIterator.next();
         // I know I'm expecting just one device.
      }

      textMessage += "Devices: " + deviceList.size() + "\n";

      textMessage += "Interfaces: " + m_usbDevice.getInterfaceCount() + "\n";
      for ( int i = 0; i < m_usbDevice.getInterfaceCount(); i++) {
         textMessage += "Interface " + i + ":\n";
         textMessage += "   ID: " + m_usbDevice.getInterface(i).getId() + "\n";
         textMessage += "   EP: " + m_usbDevice.getInterface(i).getEndpointCount() + "\n";

      }


      UsbEndpoint int0_ep0_out = m_usbDevice.getInterface(0).getEndpoint(0);
      UsbEndpoint int1_ep0_in  = m_usbDevice.getInterface(1).getEndpoint(0);
      UsbEndpoint int1_ep1_out = m_usbDevice.getInterface(1).getEndpoint(1);
      // I know I'm expecting two interfaces and three endpoints.

      UsbDeviceConnection usbConnection = m_usbManager.openDevice(m_usbDevice);

      byte[] message = new byte[1];
      message[0] = (byte) 0;

      int success = 0;

      try {
         success = usbConnection.bulkTransfer(int1_ep0_in, message, message.length, 0);
         textMessage += success + "\n";
      } catch (Exception e) {
         textMessage += e + "\n";
      }


      m_textView.setText(textMessage);
   }
```

Everything seems to work until I try a bulk transfer. I get the following exception:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.hardware.usb.UsbDeviceConnection.bulkTransfer(android.hardware.usb.UsbEndpoint, byte[], int, int)' on a null object reference.

Is my reference to the IN endpoint not valid?
`UsbEndpoint int1_ep0_in  = m_usbDevice.getInterface(1).getEndpoint(0);`
How do I determine if it is?

I'm also trying to figure out how to receive data from the USB device, because my Feather board here should echo back what it receives. I understand something like `bulkTransfer` should be used, but how? What invokes it? Is there some event listener that I need to setup that waits for data to come in on a specific endpoint?

[image]

Comment: Possibly related as upvoted answer has iteration over endpoints: [BulkTransfer & Android USB API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40120049/295004)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from your pastebin snippet looks like a CDC device. You can use [usb-serial-for-android](https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android) library to communicate with such devices

Comment: Accepting this answer for now until I can educate myself more about USB devices.

Comment: So, I don't think that library is what I'm looking for. Gave it a try and it fails to get available drivers.

Comment: for CDC devices you typically have to add a customProber for your specific VID/PID as depicted here: https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android#probing-for-unrecognized-devices

Comment: I retract my last comment. As @kai-morich said, I needed to specify VID and PID.

Answer (score 1):

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.hardware.usb.UsbDeviceConnection.bulkTransfer'

Translation: `usbConnection` is `null`.

You cannot open some USB devices, especially if there are other programs (or the kernel itself) using it.

Comment: Is that so that they can just never be opened, or do they need to be freed from what ever is using them? I'm definitely seeing that `UsbConnection` is null. So, I'm they to figure out exactly what the failure is.

The other USB device I have immediate access to is a flash drive. When I try that it also says the device cannot be open.